# How to run a program as privilege from run box in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, privileges, run-dialog

I want to start an application with admin privilege from the run dialog in Windows 7, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's my answer I suddenly think of today. It's quite surprisingly simple.

Instead of entering/pasting the application execution's name/path in the `run box`, make it in the `search box` in Windows 7's `start menu`!

Then, all you need is to right click and select `Run as admin` ^_^ I couldn't believe it is amzingly simple and I didn't think of it!

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the start menu -- after typing your command in the dialog, press Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

If you mean the actual Win+R run dialog, you can use [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) or check out the [sudo for Windows project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you want to start an application with different user privileges directly, rather than using the method above, on Windows 7 hold CTRL + SHIFT and right click, then press run as different user.